# Merge value of json object

Tags: php, json

I need to sum values of json object using **PHP**

**json**

```
{
  "links": [
    {
      "source": 9887878787,
      "target": 9999999993,
      "value": 1
    },
    {
      "source": 9999999993,
      "target": 9887878787,
      "value": 2
    }
  ]
}
```

Want to Combine value of first and second object to get

**desired output**

```
{
    "links": [
       {
         "source": 9887878787,
         "target": 9999999993,
         "value": 3
       },
       {
         "source": 9999999993,
         "target": 9887878787,
         "value": 3
       }
    ]
}
```

How can I achieve this without using javasript.I need php script for that?

Thank you a lot in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a way to do it :

```
$data = json_decode('{
  "links": [
    {
      "source": 9887878787,
      "target": 9999999993,
      "value": 1
    },
    {
      "source": 9999999993,
      "target": 9887878787,
      "value": 2
    }
  ]
}');

$sum = 0;
foreach ($data->links as $link) {
    $sum += $link->value;
}

foreach ($data->links as &$link) {
    $link->value = $sum;
}

echo json_encode($data);
```

Hope this helps.